# How I can configure radiusd.conf to enable verbose logging?

Tags: freeradius

I am going to debug freeradius while running it as daemon mode.
But I can't get verbose logging from `/var/log/freeradius/radiusd.log` such as one while running `freeradius -X`.
How I can configure `radiusd.conf` to enable full verbosity?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  It's only specifiable on the command line. If you want to run the server in multithreaded mode but with debug logging you can use `radiusd -lstdout -f -xx`